# Spark: Reducing number of rdd partitions is not reducing memory and executor cores for spark process

Tags: apache-spark

In Cloudera CDP we have got fixed size of vcores and memory to the application queues we are running with dynamic resource allocation.
We have a spark process which creates rdd from file in hdfs of 40 blocks. We are caching this RDD in memory only and then continue processing using cached rdd.
After caching rdd remainder of our task does not require much cpu and memory, so If we reduce rdd partitions let's say from 40 to 10 by repartition or coalesce then shouldn't the vcores and memory should be freed up by the spark process. I tried doing so but I have not seen any change as compared to before.

Comment: is `Dynamic Resource Allocation` enabled in your spark job ?

Comment: spark,dynamicAllocation.enabled = true from our spark conf as well as on cluster config also. The issue got fixed after we changed the value to the property spark.dynamicAllication.executorIdleTimeOut from 300s to 60s.Now we are able to get vcores & memory freed up after doing re-partitioning.